# Java Photo Album Using GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, positioning, bufferedimage, grid-layout

I want to make simple photo album in Java. To do that, I think it will be the easiest way to coordinate pictures with gridlayout.

I have my pictures' bufferedimages, I'm trying to add them into the gridlayout with the following code,

```
    BufferedImage a = GUI.createImage(current);
    Image b = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(a.getSource());

    Icon pic = new ImageIcon(b);        
    JButton picB = new JButton("Picture 1", pic );
    selectB.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    selectB.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER); //aka LEFT, for left-to-right locales
    add(picB);
```

I'm also trying to make smaller my bufferedimage with the following code,

```
int w = a.getWidth();
    int h = a.getHeight();
    BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale(0.6, 0.6);
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    after = scaleOp.filter(a, after);
```

However, eventhoug I minimize the size of the picture, the buttons are greater than the picture, and I couldnt organize the pictures.

Do you have any suggestions or new solutions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Forgive me, but I can't see in your code where you are setting the layout manager to `GridLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, I also handled the situation with the following;

Instead of using scale, I created a new function called resize

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    BufferedImage dimg = dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, img.getType());
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g.dispose();
    return dimg;
}
```

Then to my bufferedimage named bf, I called resize func and converted it to the icon

```
bf = resize(bf, bf.getWidth()/3, bf.getHeight()/3);
Image im = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(bf.getSource());
Icon ic = new ImageIcon(im);
```

Then I added the buttons with the images,

```
JButton bt = new JButton("Picture", ic);
bt.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
bt.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
add(bt);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
picB.setInsets(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
```

A BufferedImage is an Image too, hence `b` seems not to be needed.

A BufferedImage has a Graphics associated, so resizing could be done as follows:

```
BufferedImage scaled = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
scaled.getGraphics().drawImage(original, 0, 0, width, height, null);
```